# How to print an array of doubles in a column in Java

Tags: java, string-formatting

I've got 3 arrays like this:

```
String[] monthName = { "January", "February", "March",  
                       "April", "May", "June", "July",  
                       "August", "September", "October",  
                       "November", "December" };  

Double[] temperature = {68.1,69.1,72.4,75.7,79.6,82.4,83.7,83.6,82.4,78.8,74.4,69.9};
Double[] precipitation = {1.9,2.1,2.6,3.4,5.5,8.5,5.8,8.6,8.4,6.2,3.4,2.2};
```

How could I print this values like this:

```
                   Climate Data
           Location:

Month      Temperature (F)    Precipitation (in.)
*************************************************
 Jan.          51.8                  5.4
 Feb.          54.8                  4.6
 Mar.          61.1                  6.5
 Apr.          66.4                  3.6
 May           74.4                  5.0
 Jun.          80.4                  6.9
 Jul.          82.4                  8.0
 Aug.          82.1                  7.0
 Sep.          78.9                  5.0
 Oct.          69.1                  3.3
 Nov.          60.4                  3.9
 Dec.          53.7                  4.1
*************************************************
```

Comment: You can also use Sting.format.  Here's the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @Ivan - Is the homework tag still supposed to be used?

Comment: @Ivan Please don't add homework tags to posts.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method.

Here's an example that pads two Strings so they occupy 12 columns and are aligned to the left:

```
String paddedOne = String.format("%-12s", "Hello");
String paddedTwo = String.format("%-12s", "Goodbye");
System.out.println(paddedOne + paddedTwo);
```

Output:

```
Hello       Goodbye
```